# Select the records depending on the From and To dates in the date picker

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, wpf-controls

I have two `DatePicker`'s in my application and I have to select records depending on the user selection of date ( from date - To date). the below figure displays the design of my `Datepicker`. I would like to display count of the succeeded Process in the succeddedtxtBox and count of the failed Process in the failedtxtBox, depending on the date selection in these datepickers

[image]

XAML

```
      <Label>displays the succedded process</Label>
      <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Gray">
      <TextBlock FontWeight="SemiBold" FontSize="12" x:Name="success_Txtbox" Width="50" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" TextAlignment="Right"/>
      </Border>
      <Label>displays the failed process</Label>
      <Border BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1">
      <TextBlock FontWeight="SemiBold" FontSize="12" x:Name="fail_Txtbox" Width="50" TextAlignment="Left"></TextBlock>
            </Border>
```

I figured the logic for linq to query, which will look something like this.

```
   var query_success = ( from x in this.db.Processes
             where x.date = "from date" && x.date = "to date" && 
             (x.Type == "completed")
             select x).Count();
   success_Txtbox.Text = query_success.ToString();   

   var query_failed = ( from x in this.db.Processes
             where x.date = "from date" && x.date = "to date" && 
             (x.Type == "Failed")
             select x).Count();
   failed_Txtbox.Text = query_failed.ToString();
```

**UPDATE- XAML**

```
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label>From</Label>
            <Border>
                <DatePicker x:Name="fromDP"></DatePicker>
            </Border>
            <Label>To</Label>
            <Border>
                <DatePicker x:Name="toDP"></DatePicker>
            </Border>
            <Button Content="Go !" Height="23" Name="Go_Btn" Width="75" Click="Go_Btn_Click" />
        </StackPanel>
```

**UPDATED Answer**

```
 private void Go_Btn_Click(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var query_History = (this.db.Processes
                           .Where(x => x.Date >= fromDP.SelectedDate.Value && x.Date <= toDP.SelectedDate.Value));

        var query_Success = query_History.Count(p => p.Type == "Complete");
        var query_Failed = query_History.Count(p => p.Type == "Failed");

        success_Txtbox.Text = query_Success.ToString();
        fail_Txtbox.Text = query_Failed.ToString();
    }
```

I tried the above solution, but it displays 0 as the result in the txtbox .

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "in C#". LINQ is part of C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

based on your linq, if you do

```
    where x.date = "from date" && x.date = "to date"
```

you'll only get results when both datepickers are selected to the same date.

You want something more along the lines of

```
    where x.date >= datepicker_FromDate.selectedValue 
    && x.date <= datepicker_ToDate.selectedValue
```

Comment: kindly see my update in Gert Arnold's solution, do I need to setup any trigger or event, so that the result is displayed after selecting the dates ?

Comment: adding the same code you had in your example should do it, i.e.   success_Txtbox.Text = query_success.ToString();

Comment: I did already, kindly check my updated answer in my question. but I see only 0 as the result :(

Comment: right.  You need to assign some click event in the xaml, when the user selects both dates, to call your event function and update the textboxes.  Maybe a "Go" button would be good here.

Comment: you don't have the xaml for the datepickers shown, so it's hard to tell.

Comment: I will update the XAML in my question, anyhow I am trying with a button too now

Comment: with a button the syntax for the event will be <Button Click="fromDP_SelectedDateChanged" />

Answer (score 3):

Use the `SelectedDate` property to get the selected dates from the date pickers. Let's say you have the values in `DateTime?`variables `fromDate` and `toDate`. Then use a base query and address it twice to get the counts:

```
var processes = this.db.Processes
                .Where(x => x.date >= fromDate.Value && x.date <= toDate.Value);

var query_success = processes.Count(p => p.Type == "completed");
var query_failed = processes.Count(p => p.Type == "Failed");
```

Comment: Thank u for the update sir, I tried the following but I get '0' displayed in the textbox, do I have to set any event in my xaml ?

Comment: I guess you want to do this when the user picks a date (`SelectedDateChanged`).

Comment: Please add it to your post so people see what is yours.

Comment: Look in the debugger. Do `query_Success` and `query_Failed` get values > 0?

Comment: No. the count is 0, it is because i jus try to select the date in the From section. where should I place the event?

Comment: Probably in both pickers, or in a button next to them. And check `DateTime?.HasValue`.

Comment: where should I check DateTime?.HasValue